# How can I display selected events in the Top Events category screen for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to filter several events of my event list. I am trying to do it via a segmentation, but it does't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You just want to see the events filtered by the event category/action? Or by some other value?

Answer (score 1):

Events are hit based, whereas segments are session based, so any other events that also happen within the session where the target event occurs, will remain in the list when the segment is applied.

At the upper right of the Top Events Report (above the date selection picker) is the option to Edit the report. If you select Edit, you can turn the standard report into a custom report and apply a filter to the custom report to restrict it to just the Event Category that you are wanting to see the Event data for.